# Create a sim toggle application in xamarin android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]Can somebody help me to write a code for toggle dual sim in android. I could get the subscription information for both the slots using the below code. I have added an image of my requirement.

```
 TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(TelephonyService);
 SubscriptionManager smgr = (SubscriptionManager)GetSystemService(TelephonySubscriptionService);
 SubscriptionInfo sim1= smgr.GetActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(0);
 SubscriptionInfo sim2 = smgr.GetActiveSubscriptionInfoForSimSlotIndex(1);
```

Comment: I don't think that non-system apps can toggle sim cards. I'm even sure they can't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to [TelephonyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html), there is no such kind of apis exposed to control multiple SIM cards.

So I think controlling multiple SIM cards on application level is not supported .

You can try to contact manufacturer of the device to get the SDK for controlling multiple SIM cards.

As a workaround I think you can use `Intent` to call system level sim card control panel as following code:

```
 private void Bt1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
       Intent mIntent = new Intent();
       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.IccLockSettings");
       mIntent.SetComponent(comp);
       mIntent.SetAction(Intent.ActionView);
       StartActivity(mIntent);
 }
```

Comment: To open the sim settings window I have tried ComponentName comp = new ComponentName("com.android.settings.sim", "com.android.settings.sim.SimSettings");. But not seems to be working. Can you help ?

Comment: @Pradeep I have tried "com.android.settings.sim.SimSettings" it can not opened. Does SimSettings mean `StartActivity(new Intent(Android.Provider.Settings.ActionDataRoamingSettings));`. I have find the [source code](https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_settings) of `setting` I think you can check it and start any activity you want in the `setting`.